# Error when invoking creation of another form

Tags: django

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as BaseUser

CHOICE_GENDER = ((1, 'Male'), (2, 'Female'))


class Location(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return ', '.join([self.city, self.state])


class Users(BaseUser):
    user = models.OneToOneField(BaseUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gender = models.IntegerField(choices=CHOICE_GENDER)
    birth = models.DateField()
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('user',)
```

forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
from .models import Users, Location, CHOICE_GENDER


class LocationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    city = forms.CharField(max_length=75)
    country = forms.CharField(max_length=25)

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ('city', 'country',)


class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=75)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICE_GENDER)
    birth = forms.DateField()
    location = LocationForm()

    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'birth')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.gender = self.cleaned_data['gender']
        user.birth = self.cleaned_data['birth']
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

This code in forms.py doesn't work. It doesn't save LocationForm due to these errors:

```
country - This field is required.
city - This field is required.
```

I've certainly did something wrong here, but I don't know exactly what. I admit that I've jumbled the code in forms.py, especially in the save method for RegistrationForm because I don't know how to properly invoke the creation of another form and how to make a connection between two of them. I searched the Internet but I couldn't find precise info about that, so I tried to improvise but I've failed, unfortunately.
Could someone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

---

UPDATE: views.py (currently):

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        reg_form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        loc_form = LocationForm(request.POST)
        if reg_form.is_valid() and loc_form.is_valid():
            location = loc_form.save()
            reg_form.cleaned_data['location_id'] = location.id
            registration = reg_form.save()
        else:
            pass
    else:
        reg_form = RegistrationForm()
        loc_form = LocationForm()    
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'loc_form': loc_form, 'reg_form':reg_form})
```

I've also modified forms.py but I still got the error from above.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `LocationForm` inside `RegistrationForm` you can handle them seprately in your `views.py` it will result in a cleaner code and easy to handle.

```
if request.method == "POST":
    reg_form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
    loc_form = LocationForm(request.POST)
    if reg_form.is_valid() and loc_form.is_valid():
        # since in your case they are dependent on each other
        # save location form and get location object
        location = loc_form.save()
        # now you can use it in your reg_form
        reg_form.cleaned_data['location_id'] = location.id
        registration = reg_form.save()
    else:
        # no need to handle this case only for explanation
        # use the forms, with valid post data initialized 
        # at the start of current if block
        pass
else:
    # create new forms for location and registration
    reg_form = RegistrationForm()
    loc_form = LocationForm()    
return render(request, 'signup.html', {'loc_form': loc_form, 'reg_form':reg_form})
```

You can read here more on how to handle more than one nested forms in [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/).

Comment: Then how do I adapt "else" part in the code here: http://pastebin.com/raw/qHRxcApG

Comment: @MikiSoft kindly update your question or share the code in comment, do not share any links; its not advised.

Comment: How can I post the code in this reply when there's no new line? That's why I've shared it on Pastebin, it's absurd from you not to open it.

Comment: @MikiSoft on some networks PasteBin or other sharing services might be blocked, thats why I asked you to put in comment(if small) otherwise update it in Question part; otherwise it might not possible to answer ;)

Comment: Okay, I can try to explain rather than showing the code: I want if the submission of form fails or if it's not POST method to render the contents of the previous submitted data within the template (in its form to be more precise), if any.